# rake db:seed not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, seeding, faker

I am trying to seed a database with initial users.  The first two are testing accounts and populate fine:

`User.create! :name => "Name", :surname => "Lastname", :admin => 't', :email => "admin@testing.co", :encrypted_password => "Password"`

`User.create! :name => "name", :surname => "lastname", :admin => 'f', :email => "test@faker.tld", :encrypted_password => "Password"`

However, the error `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'name' for main:Object` is triggered when I try to run:

```
8.times do
 User.create! :name => Faker::Name.first_name, :surname => Faker::Name.last_name, :admin => 'f', :email => Faker::Internet.email(name + "." + surname), :encrypted_password => Faker::Internet.password(10)
end
```

I can't figure out the problem.  Any help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this:

```
8.times do
 name = Faker::Name.first_name
 surname = Faker::Name.last_name
 encrypted_password = Faker::Internet.password(10)
 user_list << [name, surname, 'f', Faker::Internet.email(name + "." + surname), encrypted_password]
end
user_list.each do |name, surname, admin, email, encrypted_password|
  User.create!(name:name, surname:surname, admin:admin, email:email, encrypted_password:encrypted_password)
end
```